# chrome.webRequest not working on Chrome 17

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have problems in chrome-extension API (chrome.webrequest).

My manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "tesst",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "permissions": ["webRequest","webRequestBlocking",
                  "http://*" ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background_page": "background.html"
}
```

My background.html

```
<script>

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(   function(info) { loldogs = [{name:'x', value: 'xx'}];  console.log("URL: " + info.url);    info.requestHeaders.push.apply(info.requestHeaders,loldogs);    for(var i in info.requestHeaders) {         for (var key in info.requestHeaders[i]){            console.log("header "+i+" ["+key+"] "+info.requestHeaders[i][key]);         }   }
        return {requestHeaders: info.requestHeaders};   },   {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},   ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);


</script>
```

When I connect to some url (ex: http://google.com), chrome not set header {name:'x', value: 'xx'} in http-request. And it does not log anythings in console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `"http://*"` to `"http://*/*"` in permissions.

Comment: "http://*/*" in permissions is like an open door!  But thank you for posting it as it actually got my script working. Then find through the error message in console what urls need permission.